# linking collection and incollection

Tags: biblatex, links

Is there a way in Biblatex to have a link in an incollection entry that creates a hyperlink to the title of the collection entry if it also appear in the bibliography.

So for example if I have:

```
 @incollection{Farrer1965Christian,
    author  = {Farrer, Austin},
    editor  = {Jocelyn Gibb},
    year    = 1965,
    title   = {The Christian Apologist},
    booktitle   = {Light on C.S. Lewis},
    publisher   = { Harcourt, Brace \& World},
    address = {New York, NY}
}
```

I would like the booktitle to be as hyperlink to the booktitle in

```
@collection{Gibb1965Light,
  editor = "Gibb, Jocelyn",
   booktitle     = "{Light on C.S. Lewis}",
   publisher    = {Harcourt, Brace \& World},
    address = {New York, NY}, 
   year           = 1965
 }
```

without doing it manually.

What I would really like is not to have to include the publisher, address and editor in the first entry.

Answer (score 9):

NB you will need to run Biber (`backend=biber`) for what follows.

Second things first:
You do not have to retype all the information from the `@collection` for the `@incollection`, if you use Biber's awesome `crossref` field.

```
@incollection{Farrer1965Christian,
  author   = {Farrer, Austin},
  title    = {The Christian Apologist},
  crossref = {Gibb1965Light},
}
@collection{Gibb1965Light,
  editor   = {Gibb, Jocelyn},
  title    = {Light on C.S. Lewis},
  publisher= {Harcourt, Brace \& World},
  address  = {New York, NY}, 
  year     = {1965},
}
```

`Farrer1965Christian` will automatically inherit all the needed fields in the right meaning, i.e. `Gibb1965Light`'s `title` will become `Farrer1965Christian`'s `booktitle`.

For the clickable hyperlink to the `booktitle`, try the following modification. It should work for all standard styles, but I'm not to sure about others.

This links to the `crossref` entry if it is not empty. Note that in some situations this might go wrong (suppose the `crossref`'d entry did not supply the `booktitle`).

```
\renewbibmacro*{booktitle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{crossref}
      {\printtext[booktitle]{%
         \printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}%
         \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
         \printfield[titlecase]{booksubtitle}}}%
      {\bibhyperref[\thefield{crossref}]{\printtext[booktitle]{%
         \printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}%
         \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
         \printfield[titlecase]{booksubtitle}}}}
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}}
```

An MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits=true,citestyle=numeric-comp,backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Farrer1965Christian,
  author   = {Farrer, Austin},
  title    = {The Christian Apologist},
  crossref = {Gibb1965Light},
}
@collection{Gibb1965Light,
  editor   = {Gibb, Jocelyn},
  title    = {Light on C.S. Lewis},
  publisher= {Harcourt, Brace \& World},
  address  = {New York, NY}, 
  year     = {1965},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{booktitle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{crossref}
      {\printtext[booktitle]{%
         \printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}%
         \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
         \printfield[titlecase]{booksubtitle}}}%
      {\bibhyperref[\thefield{crossref}]{\printtext[booktitle]{%
         \printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}%
         \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
         \printfield[titlecase]{booksubtitle}}}}
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}}

%COMMENCE
\begin{document}
  \lipsum
  Test citation by \cite{Farrer1965Christian} and \cite{Gibb1965Light}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]